# ARIMA order for trend

Tags: python, arima

I am trying to fit ARIMA model. I have 3 months data and it shows `count(float)` for every minute. Which order I should pass for `arima.fit()`?
I need to predict for every minute.

[image: Plot of my data]

[image: My ACF]

[image: My PACF]

[image: Data of weekdays]
[image: Updated_PACF]
[image: Updated_ACF]
[image: Prediction]

Comment: You should try asking on Cross validated if you are clueless about statistics.

Answer (score 0):

A basic ARIMA(p,d,q) model isn't going to work with your data.

Your data violates the assumptions of ARIMA, one of which is that the parameters have to be consistent over time.
I see clusters of 5 spikes, so I'm presuming that you have 5 busy workdays and quiet weekends.  Basic ARIMA isn't going to know the difference between a weekday and weekend, so it probably won't give you useful results.

There is such a thing as a SARIMA (Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average).  That would be useful if you were dealing with daily data points, but not really suitable for minute data either.

I would suggest that you try to filter your data so that it excludes evenings and weekends. Then you might be dealing with a dataset that has consistent parameters. If you're using python, you could try using pyramid's auto_arima() function on your filtered time series data (s) to have it try to auto-find the best parameters p, d, q.

It also does a lot of the statistical tests you might want to look into for this type of analysis.  I actually don't always agree with the auto_arima's parameter choices, but it's a start.

```
model = pyramid.arima.auto_arima(s)
print(model.summary())
```

http://pyramid-arima.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_submodules/arima.html

Comment: I excluded weekends and use auto.arima. But I got NaN for forecast.

Comment: stepwise_model = auto_arima(group, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                           start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                           d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                           error_action='ignore',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)

Comment: It'll be hard to diagnose without knowing more about the data.  What does the data represent?  ARIMA models only work on stationary time series data, or data that can be transformed into stationary time series data.  You might have to filter out evenings as well.  You might have to work with the first difference of the time series instead of the raw time series.  Basically, you have to get your data to look like it does on this site:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process  And, there's always a possibility that there is no statistical relationship, and your data is just white noise.

Comment: Data shows number of people entering office cafe every minute. It spikes at breakfast and lunch time.I am trying to predict number of people for future date and time

Comment: Ok, if you are dealing with a known periodic behavior, then a seasonal model is probably the way to go.  All ARIMA models are linear models, so in some way, shape, or form, you have to figure out how to transform your data to get it stationary.  You have to remove the non-stationary elements of the data. You should read about SARIMA(p,d,q) x (P,D,Q)^s models.  What a seasonal model does is it subtracts a known period from the data, so in your case, s=7*24*60=10080.  Then you'll be comparing Monday 10 am to the following Monday 10 am, etc.

Comment: Try reading http://www.seanabu.com/2016/03/22/time-series-seasonal-ARIMA-model-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

1) is your data even good for box -Jenkins model( ARIMA)?

2) I see higher mean in the end. There is clear seasonality in the data. ARIMA will fail. Please try seasonal based models- SARIMA as righly suggested by try, Prophet is another beautiful algo by Facebook for seasonality. - ( R implementation)
https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2017/05/facebooks-phophet-model-for-forecasting.html

3) Not just rely on ARIMA. Try other time series algos that are STL, BTS, TBATS. ( Structural Time series)  and Hybrid etc. Let me know if you want some packages information in R?

Comment: I have no background in R. Can I use Prophet in python as they have python implementation?

Comment: I am really new to Timeseries model. I have some experience in regression and classification models. Can I do this project without any background?

Comment: yes, indeed. you can get python implementation here ( facebook .github) - https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api

Comment: Time series is no big deal, think of this as regression with lagged values as independent variables. ARIMA is nothing but a regression model.  If u re interested to related regression and time series. This article might help- https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2016/08/time-series-and-fitting-regression-on.html